# Passing Constructor Arguments to a dependency of a root object as part of a single resolve in Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have the following classes (I know they are not well designed; I just want to express the Ninject problem).

I don't know how to pass the constructor arguments down to my service (which is a dependency of `Utility` which is a dependency of `MainProgram`):-

```
class MainProgram
{
    static IKernel kernel;
    static MainProgram mainProgram; 

    Utility Utility;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel(new DIModule());

        var constructorArgument1 = new ConstructorArgument("firstArg", args[0]);
        var constructorArgument2 = new ConstructorArgument("secondArg", args[1]);

        mainProgram = kernel.Get<MainProgram>(new IParameter[] { constructorArgument1, constructorArgument2 });
        mainProgram.Utility.ExportToXML();
    }


    public MainProgram(Utility utility)
    {
        this.utility = utility;
    }
}

public class Utility
{
    private IService service;
    public Utility(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    //methods to work with service
}

public class Service : IService 
{
    private readonly string firstArg;
    private readonly string secondArg;

    public Service(string firstArg, string secondArg)
    {
        this.firstArg = firstArg;
        this.secondArg = secondArg;
    }
}


class DIModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IService>().To<Service>();
        Bind<Utility>().ToSelf();
        Bind<MainProgram>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

The `kernel.Get<MainProgram>()` fails with the following message:

> Error activating string

```
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
```

I understand this is because the constructor arguments are not making their way to the IService.

Is this even the correct approach for resolving my dependencies. I read in a few places that if you use kernel.Get() "you not using DI".

Comment: I suggest supplying those values as arguments of the `ExportToXML`. The rule of thumb here is: pass config and compile-time dependencies through the constructor (or property), pass runtime dependencies through methods.

Comment: Re not doing DI if you `Get`, the point is you should have a single Composition Root and it should Resolve a Single thing (with or without using a DI Container) with lots of turtles swimming out from there (which it might  repeat lots of times). Run and buy http://manning.com/seemann and you won't need to listen to hearsay.

Answer (score 2):

See ["inherited constructor arguments" in this blog post from @Remo Gloor](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/12/30/new-features-and-changes-of-ninject-3-0/). The `shouldInherit` argument of the `ConstructorArgument` ctor needs to be passed `true` for your case to work.

A word of caution - having magic floating arguments like this is not generally a good idea - if something needs to be passed, pass it and don't confuse matters by using container tricks (i.e. what @Steven said in his comment).

(Also obviously if you can `Bind` ... `WithConstructorArgument`, that's much better, but I assume you know that.)

Perhaps you're missing an abstraction - maybe the `Service` should be asking for a `ServiceConfiguration` rather than two strings that you can easily get backwards?